# Does Evernote on the iPad have undo functionality?

Tags: ipad, applications, undo-redo

Am i wrong or it is true that the evernote app on iPad doesn't have undo funcionality ?

For example if I delete a line, it is gone for ever ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with the iPhone, if you shake the iPad vigorously, you get offered the choice of:

- Undo
- Cancel

For me, this doesn't feel at all natural on the iPad, and I imagine that's why some iPad applications (e.g. Textastic) provide their own Undo/Redo buttons.

**Edit**

Thanks to @Lizzan for also pointing out in the comments:

> There's also an Undo button in the bottom left on the numerical keyboard - makes a bit more sense than shaking the iPad.

Comment: There's also an Undo button in the bottom left on the numerical keyboard - makes a bit more sense than shaking the iPad.

Comment: Brilliant - I never noticed that. Thanks. You should probably post this as an answer - it's better than mine!

Comment: No need for that, it's the same functionality, really, only a different way of getting to it. Feel free to include it in your answer, though!